# Contacting the method on the server from client code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I am trying to use SignalR for the first time, wanting to add it to my project.

My problem right now, is that I can't get a message from the server. I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: signalRhub.Test is not a function
```

My reference to scripts look like this (which seems to work):

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.3.0.min.js"></script>
<script src='~/signalr/js'></script>
```

Here is my client code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var signalRhub = $.connection.hubSignalR;
        console.log(signalRhub);
        //Start connection
        $.connection.hub.start(function () {
            signalRhub.Test(function (response) {
                 alert("Response from server: " + response);
                //$("#testDiv").html(response);                
            });            
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my server class definition, and the method I'm trying to call (that cannot be found):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

    namespace AuthSys.SignalRhub
    {
        public class HubSignalR : Hub
        {
            public string Test()
            {
                return "Success from server";
            }
        }
    }
```

-------------------  Additional information  ---------------
[image]

I have attached a screenshot of my Firefox console. In my client code, you will notice this code:

```
console.log(signalRhub);
```

That is what you see in the Firefox console. Looking at the child called `connection`, it looks like the connection is made. Here you see the URL it generates etc. And looking at the `server`child (expanded 2 levels), it looks like it found the `Test()` method that is on the server.

My Startup.cs looks like this (If of any importance):

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(AuthSys.Startup))]
namespace AuthSys
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Any one might know what my problem is?

What I am expecting (trying to do) is to get an alert on my screen, with the string:

```
Success from server
```

that is seen in the C# class on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your *C#* code to publish your message

```
public string Test() {
   //Clients.Client("ToClientId").TestMessages("Message");//send messages to specific user
   Clients.All.TestMessages("Message"); //send messages to all user
}
```

Send method *Javascript*

```
signalRhub.server.test();//Note you didn't have created parameter, but you can create them
```

*Javascript* method like this

```
signalRhub.client.TestMessages = function (response) {
    alert("Response from server: " + response);
};
```

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot. A note: the Test() in signalRhub.server.Test(); must be changed to lowercase for it to work. So it must be: signalRhub.server.test();